# For Each loop with 2 parent 'columns'

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to expand on some working code, and not sure how to do it.
Basicly the information can be under either information or some othertitle.
but i dont care for this split, i just want to do a foreach for all of them together.

Basicly i currently run a for each loop like this:

```
foreach ($info_array['information'] as $item) {... do something }
```

Would it be possible to somehow say, For each info_array 'information' & 'othertitle' as $item?

array is structured like:

```
information
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
othertitle
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
   random number
      price
      amount
      total
```

i tried this, but that didnt work:

```
foreach ($item_array['information'] as $item and $item_array['othertitle'] as $item)
```

Comment: Show what you want to do with the items in the loop.

Comment: What you try to achieve by those double loop?

Comment: i am not trying to do a double loop. i just want all the data thats under 'random number'  and i don't care if the parent is 'information'  or 'othertitle'.  i just dont know how to do a loop in a way to get all the prices/amounts/totals for both the "information" and "othertitle" part at once

Comment: As `othertitle` __follows__ `information` two loops - one after another - is enough.

Comment: @u_mulder so best way to do this wouldnt be to combine it?  but just run 1 after the other? (so 2 for each loops?)  (i did think of that, but thought/hoped there was a more elegant solution XD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first idea that comes in mind is just use two loops - first one iterates over `$item_array['information']`, second one - over `$item_array['othertitle']`. Something like this:

```php
foreach ($item_array['information'] as $item) {
    echo $item['key1'] . ' -> ' . $item['key2'];
}
foreach ($item_array['othertitle'] as $item) {
    echo $item['key1'] . ' -> ' . $item['key2'];
}
```

But, if you do the same output for each element of each array, you can do this:

```php
$keys = ['information', 'othertitle'];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo 'Key is ' . $key . '<br />';
    foreach ($item_array[$key] as $item) {
        echo $item['key1'] . ' -> ' . $item['key2'];
    }
}
```

And even it the output for arrays is different - you can solve it in this way:

```php
$keys = ['information', 'othertitle'];
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo 'Key is ' . $key . '<br />';
    foreach ($item_array[$key] as $item) {
        if ('information' === $key) {
            echo 'Info: ' . $item['key1'] . ' -> ' . $item['key2'];
        } else {
            echo 'Ttile: ' . $item['key1'] . ' and ' . $item['key2'];
        }
    }
}
```

And if you have to iterate over all subarrays of `$item_array`, the solution is the same as in @AbraCadaver answer:

```php
foreach ($item_array as $key => $items) {
    echo 'Key is ' . $key . '<br />';
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ('information' === $key) {
            echo 'Info: ' . $item['key1'] . ' -> ' . $item['key2'];
        } else {
            echo 'Ttile: ' . $item['key1'] . ' and ' . $item['key2'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i solved it now, i used a bit from both your answers, but eventually for the main part just went with 2 loops, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the indexes you could `array_merge` or use `+`:

```
foreach ($item_array['information'] + $item_array['othertitle'] as $item) {
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise you need two loops:

```
foreach ($item_array as $array) {
    foreach($array as $item) {
        // do something
    }
}
```